# Apex - 0% Code Coverage!

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, deployment

I've developed a trigger that converts a currency field, **Amount** (i.e. $1,000) into words, **Currency_text__c** (i.e. One Thousand).

This is achieved via Salesforce a 'FundingAwardTrigger' on the FundingAward object (part of the Grantmaking package).  The trigger functions perfectly in Sandbox.  When I run the tests in Sandbox, I get 100% coverage.

When I validate the Inbound Change Set in Prod, I get the following error:

Code Coverage Failure:
The following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage.
FundingAwardTrigger

Here's my test class:

```java
@isTest
private class FundingAwardTriggerTest {
    
    @isTest static void testTriggerOnInsert() {
        // Create a test record for the insert operation
        FundingAward testAwardInsert = new FundingAward(Name = 'Test Insert', Amount = 100);
    
        // Start the test context
        Test.startTest();
    
        // Perform the insert operation
        insert testAwardInsert;
    
        // Stop the test context
        Test.stopTest();
    
        // Retrieve the inserted record and assert the result
        testAwardInsert = [SELECT Currency_Text__c FROM FundingAward WHERE Id = :testAwardInsert.Id];
        System.assertEquals('One Hundred', testAwardInsert.Currency_Text__c, 'Trigger did not work as expected on insert');
    }
    
    @isTest static void testTriggerOnUpdate() {
        // Create and insert a record for the update operation
        FundingAward testAwardUpdate = new FundingAward(Name = 'Test Update', Amount = 100);
        insert testAwardUpdate;
    
        // Start the test context
        Test.startTest();
    
        // Perform the update operation
        testAwardUpdate.Amount = 200;
        update testAwardUpdate;
    
        // Stop the test context
        Test.stopTest();
    
        // Retrieve the updated record and assert the result
        testAwardUpdate = [SELECT Currency_Text__c FROM FundingAward WHERE Id = :testAwardUpdate.Id];
        System.assertEquals('Two Hundred', testAwardUpdate.Currency_Text__c, 'Trigger did not work as expected on update');
    }
    
    @isTest static void testBulkOperation() {
        // Create multiple records for testing bulk operation
        List<FundingAward> awards = new List<FundingAward>();
        for (Integer i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            awards.add(new FundingAward(Name = 'Bulk Test Award ' + i, Amount = i * 100));
        }
    
        // Start the test context
        Test.startTest();
    
        // Perform bulk insert
        insert awards;
    
        // Update the records for bulk update test
        for (Integer i = 0; i < awards.size(); i++) {
            awards[i].Amount += 1000;
        }
    
        // Perform bulk update
        update awards;
    
        // Stop the test context
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Why would my test class show 100% in sandbox but 0% in prod?

And for context, here is my Apex class:

```java
public class CurrencyToWords {
    public static String convert(Decimal amount) {
        if (amount == null) return '';

        // Convert Decimal to Integer for easier handling
        Integer intAmount = amount.intValue();

        // Return "Zero" immediately if amount is 0
        if (intAmount == 0) {
            return 'Zero';
        }
        
        // Arrays for number names
        String[] units = new String[]{'Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'};
        String[] teens = new String[]{'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen'};
        String[] tens = new String[]{'', 'Ten', 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety'};

        String result = '';

        // Handling millions
        Integer millions = intAmount / 1000000;
        result += millions > 0 ? units[millions] + ' Million ' : '';
        intAmount -= millions * 1000000; // Remaining amount after subtracting millions

        // Handling hundreds of thousands
        Integer hundredThousands = intAmount / 1000;
        result += hundredThousands > 0 ? convertHundreds(hundredThousands) + ' Thousand ' : '';
        intAmount -= hundredThousands * 1000; // Remaining amount after subtracting hundred thousands

        // Handling the rest (hundreds, tens, and ones)
        if (intAmount > 0) {
            result += convertHundreds(intAmount);
        }

        return result.trim();
    }

    // Helper method to convert hundreds part
    private static String convertHundreds(Integer amount) {
        String[] units = new String[]{'Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'};
        String[] teens = new String[]{'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen'};
        String[] tens = new String[]{'', 'Ten', 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety'};

        String result = '';

        Integer hundreds = amount / 100;
        result += hundreds > 0 ? units[hundreds] + ' Hundred ' : '';

        Integer lastTwoDigits = amount - (hundreds * 100); // Calculating the last two digits manually

        if (lastTwoDigits < 20 && lastTwoDigits > 9) {
            result += teens[lastTwoDigits - 10] + ' ';
        } else {
            Integer tensPlace = lastTwoDigits / 10;
            Integer onesPlace = lastTwoDigits - (tensPlace * 10); // Calculating ones place manually

            if (tensPlace > 0) {
                result += tens[tensPlace] + ' ';
            }
            if (onesPlace > 0) {
                result += units[onesPlace] + ' ';
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And the trigger:

```java
trigger FundingAwardTrigger on FundingAward (before insert, before update) {
    for (FundingAward fa : Trigger.new) {
        fa.Currency_Text__c = CurrencyToWords.convert(fa.Amount);
    }
}
```

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  The FundingAwardTriggerTest test class was omitted from my outbound change set.  Including it solved the issue!